# Universal String selector for Javascript?

Tags: javascript, string, replace, selector

I have something like

```
x.getElementById("foo" + rowIndex);
```

There are a couple of cases that have some other string before the "foo" in the ID,  and my question is if there are any replacements (like the "%" in SQL) that I could use to add something else to the "foo" like

```
x.getElementById("%foo" + rowIndex);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you use `querySelector` instead of `getElementById`, you can pass a selector string that selects an ID which *ends with* the substring you want, for example:

```
x.querySelector('[id$="foo' + rowIndex + '"]');
```

```js
const rowIndex = 3;
console.log(document.querySelector('[id$="foo' + rowIndex + '"]'));
```

```html
<div id="barfoo3">text</div>
```

(of course, if you want to select *all* elements whose ID ends with that, use `querySelectorAll` instead of `querySelector`)

That said, note that such dynamic IDs are somewhat of a code smell - you might consider if there are more elegant alternative methods.

Comment: It worked, thank you! Gonna choose it as the correct answer when I'm able to, in 10 minutes. Yes, I get it that it's not an elegant way but I can't modify the methods, it's a humongous application.